# Deploying Solr Translator in Jboss

Tags: java, solr, jboss, wildfly, teiid

I am trying to use the embedded JCA connector to connect to a Solr Source to be able to then deploy that as native VDB in TEIID to query SOLR using SQL. Below is the translator and resource adapter configuration I have under standalone.xml:

translator:

```
<translator name="solr" module="org.jboss.teiid.translator.solr"/>
```

resource adapter:

```
<resource-adapter id="solrDS">
                    <module slot="main" id="org.jboss.teiid.resource-adapter.solr"/>
                    <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                    <connection-definitions>
                        <connection-definition class-name="org.teiid.resource.adapter.solr.SolrManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/solrDS" enabled="true" pool-name="solrDS">
                            <config-property name="CoreName">
                                document_shard3_replica_n8
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="url">
                                http://<solr-server>:8983/solr
                            </config-property>
                        </connection-definition>
                    </connection-definitions>
</resource-adapter>
```

When I deploy the VDB, I am getting following error in server.log:

```
WARN  [org.teiid.RUNTIME] (Worker8) TEIID50036 VDB SolrSourceModel.1 model "SolrSourceModel" metadata failed to load. Reason:java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Thank you and appreciate if I can get any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the libraries may have gone out of support, you would have to debug and see what causing the NPE and fix it in the connector code.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. Can you please suggest the path(s) where the solr jars would need to be updated.

Comment: if you are using wildfly based server look in the "modules" directory and search "solr"